# You are not allowed to edit '...' package information

Tags: python, pypi

I just registered a new package in PyPI. Once I uploaded it and it's appears to be already published on a website.

Next, I slightly changed source code, bumped to a new version and performed

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

command from the shell. And this is a result:

```
Submitting dist/...-0.2.2.tar.gz to http://pypi.python.org/pypi
Upload failed (403): You are not allowed to edit '...' package information
```

My ~/.pypirc information is correct (I double-checked it and earlier I suffered from "must be authenticated" problem which is already solved here.

Any ideas? May it be a fresh registration side-effect (I just created account on PyPI today, about an hour ago)?

Comment: I investigated, expermented and found that this happend because I uploaded package, but havent registered it prior to uploading. Because I manually created .pypirc and registered account on the website, first upload was successful.

After I deleted package, registered it and uploaded again, everything looks ok.

Comment: You should add that as an answer to your question, rather than a comment! Then it's easy to see in a search that this has been solved.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I investigated, experimented and found that this happend because I uploaded package, but havent registered it prior to uploading. Because I manually created .pypirc and registered account on the website, first upload was successful. After I deleted package, registered it and uploaded again, everything looks ok.

Answer (score 39):

You need to register it first.

```
python setup.py register
```

Then you can

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

Comment: This fixed the exact issue for me. Thanks. No need to delete any package etc. Just register and upload separately.

Comment: This now gives: server response (410): This API is no longer supported, instead simply upload the file.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error because I created my account online, but did not confirm my verification e-mail first. Once I confirmed the account was mine and that I agreed to the terms, the next time I ran `python setup.py sdist register upload` it worked, returning a `Server response (200): OK`

This was all with a `~/.pypirc` with contents like this:

```
[server-login]
username:<username>
password:<plain-text password>
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the answer here solves your problem, try to remove `~/.pypirc` then `python setup.py register` before trying again for another submission.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me.

I had to register the package with Twine first:

```
twine register dist/my-package-1.0.0.tar.gz
```

Then you can upload

```
twine upload dist/*
```

See also this [thread on GitHub](https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/21).